# debounce (AfterValueChanged) Not working properly

Tags: html, angular

I'm tryig to create a field that evaluates it's content some time after I stopped typing data into it.
I was able to make it work in a previous form with this:

```
<div class="input-field">
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="distance" 
[floatInput]="true" 
[ngClass]="{ 'invalid': ( form.get( 'distance' ).hasError('required') ) }" [formControl]="form.get( 'distance' )" 
debounce (afterValueChanged)="setDistance( distance )"  
min="2" value="1" >
</div>
```

The debounce part is the important one. This works as intended. However, I need to make it work on another field, and it does not work at all. The HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="input-field centerblock fullwidth">
<input type="text" 
[disabled]="!editable" 
[floatInput]="true" placeholder="0.00" 
[id]="'oap'+pos" [(ngModel)]="item.monto" 
debounce (afterValueChanged)="montoActualizado( $event.target.value, item)" >
</div>
```

Does anyone know why this could not be working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've forgot to add `[formControl]="form.get( 'item.monto' )"`:

```
<div class="input-field centerblock fullwidth">
<input type="text" 
[disabled]="!editable"
[formControl]="form.get( 'item.monto' )" 
[floatInput]="true" placeholder="0.00" 
[id]="'oap'+pos" [(ngModel)]="item.monto" 
debounce (afterValueChanged)="montoActualizado( $event.target.value, item)" >
</div>
```

Comment: Why would I need to add the form control in there? Im going to check this now

Comment: I m not able to use formcontrol directives in this HTML because it is not linked to a form. However, I was able to get a kind of similar effect using (change) directive. I have to click outside the field for it to work, but it does kind of work.